# Edit button color on magento mercado theme

Tags: css, magento, colors

I have a site: thefashionshop.nl
But you see that the button color of the menu is grey. I dont find anything in the css. Maybe you will find?
Can you please help me.
Greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you should spell your domain right when asking for help, if you cant even spell your own domain, it doesnt speak much for the work you want me to check.

```
Thefashionshop.nl

Styles.css Line 537
#nav li.level0
Background: CHANGE YOUR COLOR HERE
```

Comment: i dont want the background but i want the color of the menu buttons

Comment: Wouldn't that be Styles.css Nick? :)

Comment: I cant find anything in styles.css

Comment: Well Played @Rounder :p

Comment: Also, You will notice the color of the button is defined by the "Background" indicator as mentioned above.